# Natural filtration for a transformation of a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, filtrations

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion on the filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in T},\mathbb{P})$, where $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in T}$ is the natural filtration of $W$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(W_s,s\leq t)$ for every $t\in T$.

Let's say that I want to change probability via Girsanov's theorem, so I switch to $\mathbb{Q}$ that makes $B_t = W_t - \phi t$ a Brownian motion, where $\phi$ is a constant.

I wonder: does $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in T}$ remain the natural filtration also for $B$?

Comment: Consider a simpler question. Is $\sigma(X)=\sigma(X+a)$, where $X$ is a r.v. and $a$ is a constant?

Comment: Could you clarify please?